# Pressure at great oceanic depths: is it the same as "normal" pressure?

Tags: pressure

I read that water pressure at great depths would crush a human. But there are animals, like whales, that seem to be able to descend to such depths unharmed. I realize there are physiological differences between whales and humans that allow this.

But what I wonder is, would a solid object, like an ingot of gold, be affected by the pressure as such an object would be affected in a mechanical press? Or is the uniformity of pressure the reason why the ingot would not flatten out? Would the pressure however cause an increase or decrease in temperature in the ingot?

Comment: The ingot would respond to that pressure. How big is the change is different. If the water column would be high enough, the ingot would flatten as under a press machine.

Comment: why would it flatten if the pressure is uniform, same on sides as well as top and bottom.

Comment: Because that P must be cancelled out by the internal one, ie repulsion between atoms. When you reach that situation flattering ceases. But I see the point. Rather than top and bottom, P would be at every side and edge. But stil, it depends on the shape of the objects and anisotropy. A generic "shrinking" is more appropriate in the case of an object *surrounded* by water . Extent of the effect might be negligible on the effective P under the deepest sink, anyway. A rubber block forced to stay down there would shrink, a steel one likely not. But this is computable at least.

Answer (score 0):

As solids and liquids do not compress as gasses do, metals would remain the same. The only temperature changes would be the normal equilibration with the surrounding water temperature. When animals go deeper in water the gasses in their body compress. Animals that live at great depth are normalized to their environment. Human divers breathing compressed air should not go much more than 33 feet deep for extended periods of time, or nitrogen build up can cause problems. Highly trained divers can usually go, in reasonable safety, a little below 200 feet with compressed air. Breathing special helium, nitrogen, and oxygen mixes will allow them to go a few hundred feet more.

Comment: I read that at, say, a mile beneath the ocean, the pressure is like a car on every square inch of the human body. That would, one might think, have an effect on any material but if it does not, I am guessing that is due to the pressure being uniformly distributed.

Comment: It is not the pressure that kills you, but the *difference* in pressure inside and outside your body. Even when you are in air at sea level, the force from the air pressure is like the weight of a car on every square *foot* of your body. That doesn't bother you at all because the gas pressure *inside* your body is exactly the same.