# Would gas inside of non-compressible material be affected by pressure in the deep ocean?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, gas, oceanography

I was thinking about the pressure of the deep ocean and was curious if gasses inside of a non-compressible container would experience the extreme pressures associated with great depth. I'm sort of thinking about James Cameron's metal sphere, or a hypothetical titanium sphere with gas in the center. If you dropped to the bottom of Mariana's Trench inside of such a sphere, would there be a change in the internal gas pressure?

I'm new to Physics Stack Exchange, so didn't know where best to put this question.

[This post was sort of related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/490388/pressure-at-great-oceanic-depths-is-it-the-same-as-normal-pressure/490395#490395)

Comment: No material is absolutely incompressible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the container truly is incompressible, then its volume cannot change, meaning regardless where it is, its pressure should stay the same. This off-course assumes that its temperature also stays the same.

If the gas is any ordinary gas like air (and its behavior approximates that of an ideal gas), then you can think about how it behaves under different temperatures, volumes and pressures by considering the ideal gas equation $$PV=nRT$$ meaning that $$\frac{PV}{T} = \text{constant}$$

This tells us that if volume decreases (it gets compressed), then pressure increases, and vice-versa. Also, if the temperature decreases, then pressure decreases, and vice-versa. Assuming the object containing the gas cannot be compressed, and the cooler temperature of the surrounding deep sea water does not affect the gas, then the pressure of the gas will stay the same.